# ZF2 - what will be dispatched if router matches multiple routes?

Tags: zend-framework2

So - what if I have a url that might be matched against many routes... which route will win?  Which action will be dispatched?

Is it simple- first defined - first dispatched?

Here's routes for example:

```
'route-catchall' => array(
    'type' => 'regex',
    'options' => array(
        'regex' => '/api/v1/.*',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'IndexController',
            'action'     => 'apiCatchAll',
        ),
    ),
),
'route-test1' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/api/v1/route1',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'IndexController',
            'action'     => 'apiRoute1',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Would this url `example.com/api/v1/route1` be routed to `apiRoute1` or  `apiCatchAll`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since routes attached to the route stack are stored in a [priority list](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/SimpleRouteStack.php#L49), the first matched route will win.

Routes are attached to the main route with a [`priority` setting](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/SimpleRouteStack.php#L252-L280). Higher priority means the route is checked first. By default, the first attached route is read (if they all have same priority or no priority at all).

```php
'route-catchall' => array(
    'type' => 'regex',
    'options' => array(
        'regex' => '/api/v1/.*',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'IndexController',
            'action'     => 'apiCatchAll',
        ),
    ),
    'priority' => -1000,
),
'route-test1' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/api/v1/route1',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'IndexController',
            'action'     => 'apiRoute1',
        ),
    ),
    'priority' => 9001, // it's over 9000!
),
```

In this example, `route-test1` will be matched first because of its high priority.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize there was a priority setting.

Comment: can we assume if no priority is specified it is the same as specifying a priority of zero?

Comment: I think the default priority in ZF2 things is `1`, but it's a per-listener thing (queue and lists are different). See https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stdlib/blob/64947b4930550721b97d2e7567765cde113b1173/src/PriorityQueue.php#L62 and https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stdlib/blob/64947b4930550721b97d2e7567765cde113b1173/src/PriorityList.php#L63 - I suppose that's an inconsistency that needs fixing :-(

Comment: ...took me a couple of go's before I realised priority 1 was less important than priority 2 >___< ...so the higher the number, the higher the priority! Uduh!