# Zend Framework 1 Routing * Params in Adminurl

Tags: php, zend-framework

I got a problem solving an variable Adminurl in Zend Framework 1.
The Route looks fine and should work, it do except if i give parameters.
Thanks for anyone who could help.
Why this will not work?

$adminpath is simple valid string.

```
'resources' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'backend' => array(                 
                'route' => $adminpath.'/:module/:controller/:action/*'
            )
        )
    )
),
```

It returns:

```
http://localhost/cms/admin/AppB/update/activate/moduleName/AppCm
```

An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (admin)
Stack trace:

Request Parameters:

```
array (
  'controller' => 'admin',
  'action' => 'AppB',
  'update' => 'activate',
  'moduleName' => 'AppCm',
  'module' => 'App',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two intersected routes. They are both can parse this URL, but someone parse first, and stops an URL-recognition process. Default route parse URL first and returns

```
'module' => 'App',
'controller' => 'admin',
'action' => 'AppB',
```

Try to put defaultRoute initialization

```
/* @var Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite $router */
$router->addDefaultRoutes();
/*init of '/:module/:controller/:action/*' route*/
```

after adding of all other routes .

Sometimes it is important to regulate route priority directly from config. To do this, you can add `priority` parameter in a routes config, for example:

```
'routes' => array(
    'backend' => array(                 
        'route' => $adminpath.'/:module/:controller/:action/*',
        'priority' => 555
    ),
 )
```

And sort a config by priority before the routes config would add to router ( `$router->addConfig` call ). [In ZF2 route priority param is native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122366/zf2-what-will-be-dispatched-if-router-matches-multiple-routes).